# Obtaining Gas and Gas Price Solidity

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, gas-refund

I added the following two lines of code to my function:

```
uint gas_remaining = msg.gas;
//irrelevant code....
refund = refund + ((gas_remaining - msg.gas) * tx.gasprice);
```

For some reason this is causing the following error:

```
transact to browser/ballot.sol:Lottery.buyT errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where is `refund` defined? and what is the value of it before that line?

Comment: @mankee It is unlikely that the `refund` line will cause a revert.